# Explicit Equation Trouble of Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\int 1 dt=\int\frac{1}{\sin z-1}dz
\\=\int\frac{1}{\sin z-1}.\frac{\sin z+1}{\sin z+1}dz
\\=\int\frac{\sin z+1}{-\cos^2 z}dz$$

I need the explicit solution of this integral where $z = y - t$. Here is a hint from my professor, but I don't understand where he was going with this: "change $z$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}-v$. Then use trigonometric formulas to pass from cos v and sin v to cos(v/2) and sin(v/2)."

$v$??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral result will be $t+c=-\sec z-\tan z=-\frac{1+\sin z}{\cos z}$ using the given
$$1+\sin z=1+\cos (\frac{\pi}{2}-z)=1+\cos v=1+2\cos^2 \frac{v}{2}-1=2\cos^2 \frac{v}{2}
\\ \cos z=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-z)=\sin v=2\sin\frac{v}{2}\cos\frac{v}{2}$$ So the integral becomes$$t+c=\cot\frac{v}{2}$$ you can complete

Comment: but what is $v$?

Comment: $v=2\cot^{-1}(t+c)$

Comment: Well, yes, but.. I guess I don't know why I thought knowing $v$ was important. $y$ is what I needed

Comment: The problem is in the term $1$, you have to cancel it to get one function on the right hand side

Comment: do you accept this